# The integral of this horrible looking expression

Tags: trigonometry, indefinite-integrals, inverse

Whats the $$\int (\cos(\tan^{-1}(\sin(\cot^{-1}x))))^2dx$$ no idea what to substitute already this is looking bad and that square is making things worse. Please help Thanks!!

Comment: Why a downvote i have no idea what to do so cant provide any efforts

Comment: @JackLam exactly from that he can convert $\cot ^{-1} x$ to $\sin ^{-1} x$ and then the equation can be reduced easily.

Comment: I did not downvote you, but I can see why someone would. Even if you have no idea how to proceed, you could still give more context. How did you get this problem? What did you try?

Answer (score 8):

The following identity can be proven by drawing a triangle and labelling values appropriately:

$$\sin{(\cot^{-1}{(x)})} \equiv \cos{(\tan^{-1}{(x)})} \equiv \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$

The integrand is simply the square of the two-composition of the above expression.

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$

$$f\circ f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{1+x^2}}}=\sqrt{\frac{1+x^2}{2+x^2}}$$

$$\int \frac{1+x^2}{2+x^2}\text{d}x$$

The rest is easy enough to do.